# Exception while running Selenium on Linux - 'Driver version unknown' error

Tags: java, linux, selenium

I am new to Selenium and have written a code to run a test case in firefox's headless mode. It is working on Windows 7 but when I tried to do the same on Centos 7.3 OS using RemoteWebDriver running into this exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, firefox_binary: /us
/bin/firefox, marionette: false, moz:firefoxOptions: {args: [--disable-web-security, --headless], binary: /usr/bin/firefox, prefs: {}}}                                  
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'                                                                                                     
System info: host: 'localhost.localdomain', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-514.26.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_73'      
Driver info: driver.version: unknown                                                                                                                                     
        at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:117) ~[na:na]                                                                  
        at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:84) ~[na:na]                                                                             
        at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:68) ~[na:na]                                                                              
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]                                                         
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]                                                         
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) ~[na:na]                                                                           
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535) ~[na:na]                                                                       
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[na:na]                                                                
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[na:na]                                                               
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[na:na]                                                                
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253) ~[na:na]                                                               
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) ~[na:na]                                                                 
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) ~[na:na]                                                                        
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[na:na]                                                                
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) ~[na:na]                                                                 
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155) ~[na:na]                                                                
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[na:na]                                                                    
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[na:na]                                                                  
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561) ~[na:na]                                                                                          
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334) ~[na:na]                                                                                
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) ~[na:na]                                                                      
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) ~[na:na]                                                      
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104) ~[na:na]                                                                                
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) ~[na:na]                                                                             
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247) ~[na:na]                                                         
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140) ~[na:na]                                                           
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131) ~[na:na]                                                               
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243) ~[na:na]                                         
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679) ~[na:na]                                                                 
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597) ~[na:na]                                                                  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
```

I even specified the driver version in the DesiredCapabilities but no luck. 
I have even tried with ChromeDriver but still I get the same exception. Here are some of the versions I tried with.

```
Selenium Standalone - 2.53.0, 3.4.0, 3.8.1 etc
Gecko Driver - 0.16.0, 0.18.0, 0.19.1 etc
Chrome Driver - 2.18, 2.30, 2.35 etc
Mozilla - 45.7, 55.0.3, 57.0 etc
Chrome -  45.0.2454.101-1, 64.0.3282.119-1 etc
```

I am running the selenium standalone hub and node on the same server.
Here is the code snippet for the same.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/root/selenium/driver/geckodriver");

FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--disable-web-security", "--headless");

String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);

FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions().setLegacy(true);
firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + "localhost" + ":" + "4444" + "/wd/hub"), firefoxOptions.toCapabilities());
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://google.com/");

// Take snapshot of browser
File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
try {
FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File("ffsnapshot.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
driver.quit();
```

I am even running an Xvfb server for virtually running firefox. Please correct me if my approach/code is wrong and also on how to get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working for firefox by adding this property.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because the selenium server cannot find chromedriver
if your chromedriver is put in /usr/local/bin/
execute:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: Should it really be owned by `root`?

Comment: @afit I'm not sure, do you have an opinion